# Const, static, extern and their combinations in C and C++

Tags: c++, c

1) How are static, extern and const and their use is different in C and C++? (Default Linkage and other differences)

2) Following declarations and definitions are allowed in a header file used in C which is then included in multiple files.

```
static int testvar = 233;
extern int one;
extern int show();
int abc;
const int xyz;  // const int xyz = 123; produces error
```

The const **definition** produces and error during compilation(maybe because of multiple definitions). However I can **declare** a const variable in header file but since we can define it providing a value and neither can we assign a value in the files this header is included in, it effectively is useless. Is there a way to define const in a header file and then access it in multiple files by including the header?

3) What changes(if at all) needs to be done so that this header can be included in multiple files in **C++**?

4) consider the following

**header.h**

```
static int z = 23;
```

**test.c**

```
#include"header.h"

z = 33;  //gives error redefinition of z!!!??

void abc()
{
    z = 33;  //perfectly fine here!!??
}
```

static vars defined/declared in header have internal linkage in each file means each file will have a separate copy of that variable. Then why does assigning a value to that var outside any function gives redefinition error while it is perfectly file inside a function?

Edit: added a 4th question. This is very confusing.

**PS: Now I am looking for answers to question 1 and 4 only.

Comment: Do you want to compile the same code with C and C++? Or are you translating existing code from one language to the other? Or just writing new code in C++ and wondering how it's best to do it?

Comment: I am not translating. I have read somewhere that there are difference in meaning of static extern and/or extern in C and C++. For now I am working on C and want to know if the same code would work in c++, if not what changes needs to be done.

As for 4th question it was written in C and i couldnt understand the reason that was causing error.

Comment: Regarding question 4, i *guess* that the first `z = 33` uses the "implicit-int" rule, that is, you (knowingly or accidentally) wrote `z = 33` instead of the proper form `int z = 33`, so it's like defining the variable twice in a row (`extern int z = 33; int z = 33`), which is wrong. The second `z = 33` in **test.c** is just an assignment (it's OK to assign twice, even `z = 33; z = 34;` is OK).

Comment: this means the expression z=33 defaults to int z = 33; (yes there was something like that in error message when i compile the program)
and it conflicts with static int z = 23 in header file. Am i right?

Answer (score 5):

1)

static means to not put an object in the global symbol table.  On the plus side, you can have multiply defined symbols without a problem.  On the down side, there aren't symbols generated for any static variables/methods, so it can make debugging harder.

2&3)

In the header:

```
extern const int xyz;
```

In a source file that includes the header (ideally the same .cc whose name matches the .h):

```
const int xyz = 123;
```

This way everyone knows about xyz but it's only defined in one source file.

Comment: +1, but `abc` also needs to be dealt with. Either make it `extern` or `static`.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker abc works fine in C. when i include the header in 2 or more files only one copy of abc is maintained which can be assigned a value and use in expressions as required and all the files.

Comment: @digital ghost: And is there a difference in meaning and linkage of static when used in C++?

Comment: Oops, then. And no, static in this context has the same meaning in c++.

Comment: @YogenderSingh Yes, static means the symbol will not be added to the global symbol table, so you can't reference the symbol at runtime but you also don't have to worry about duplicate symbols.

Answer (score 3):

> I can declare a const variable in header file but since we can define it providing a value and neither can we assign a value in the files this header is included in, it effectively is useless.

If you want an externally-linked symbol, you can declare it in the header file and then define it in *exactly* one of your source files. You get to choose which one.

However, for a `const int` there's usually no point it having external linkage. Just give it internal linkage with `static const int xyz = 123;` in the header.

That's for C: in C++ `const` globals have internal linkage by default.

Comment: Shouldn't external linkage be preferred for const as well, as it will avoid copying in each translation unit?

Comment: @vivek2k6: what are the expected benefits of avoiding having a copy of an `int` in each translation unit? Typically it is beneficial to inline small things. So, you want the copies.

Comment: What if such const are of string type? Here, external linkage should be preferred to avoid multiple copies, right?

Comment: @vivek2k6: in principle sure, if your objects are big enough you might want to reduce the size of your binaries. If all you care about is binary size, share everything (well, still not const ints, since a fixup to a shared int is probably bigger than the int, but share anything substantial). But if literally all you care about is binary size you'll likely end up with tiny executables that run slowly and are hard to maintain ;-)

Comment: "run slowly and are hard to maintain" why is this? Are you saying if binary size is not of concern, we should create multiple copies of const of substantial size, and it would be fast? Please elaborate!!

Comment: @vivek2k6: I'm saying that if you optimize for one thing and ignore everything else, then usually everything else will end up bad.

Answer (score 1):

(OP: You asked several questions so you are getting partial answers)

To answer this one

> Is there a way to define const in a header file and then access it in multiple files by including the header?

You can put the declaration, including the value, of the `const` variable, in a header file:

```
extern const int xyz = 123; // note: extern
```

Then put the definition in exactly one source file:

```
const int xyz; // note: no value provided
```

This only works in c++, not in C (or rather, i believe it doesn't work in C; never checked though).

Comment: extern const int xyz; in header and const int xyz in exactly one file seem to work in C.

Answer (score 0):

1) static: is used to declare function or variable as local. they will be used only in the file where defined. if they are defined in a header file so they will be used in the files which include this file

extern is used to import external variable or function. the variable or the function should be defined in other file and should not defined with static

2) instead of define const with `const int X = 5` you can use an alternate solution by using macros: `#define X 5`